# When $\int_M \exp(-d_M(x,y)^2/t) dvol(y)$ becomes constant for a Riemannian manifold $M$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a closed and connected Riemannian manifold. $d_M$ is its geodesic metric and $dvol_M$ is its standard volume measure. For each $t>0$, define a map $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ in the following way:

$$f_t(x):=\int_M e^{-\frac{d_M(x,y)^2}{t}} dvol_M(y).$$

Then, when this $f_t$ becomes constant map? Obviously it becomes constant if $M$ is symmetric, like $S^n$. But do we have more rich characterization?

This seems a simple question, so it might be a classical one. But I'm not expert in differential geometry. Is there any related reference about this question?

Comment: This paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485890018 seems relevant.

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer: Let $u(x,s)$ be the function such that
$$\mathrm{Vol}{\Big \{} y \in M: s_1 \leq d(x,y)^2 \leq s_2 {\Big \}} = \int_{s=s_1}^{s_2} u(x,s) ds.$$
Then your $f_t(x)$ is the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of $u(x,s)$. Since a function is determined by its Laplace transform, $f_t$ is constant in $x$ if and only if $u(x,s)$ is constant in $x$. It seems a bit more natural to work with the function $v(x,r)$ such that 
$$\mathrm{Vol}{\Big \{} y \in M: r_1 \leq d(x,y) \leq r_2 {\Big \}} = \int_{r=r_1}^{r_2} v(x,r) dr.$$
These are related by $v(x,r) = 2 r u(x,r^2)$ (just substitute $s=r^2$ in the integral), so an equivalent condition is that $v(x,r)$ is constant in $x$.

I couldn't find any references on this condition, though, and I didn't easily see how to make such a space that isn't symmetric.

Comment: An immediate consequence of this is that the scalar curvature must be constant. I'm wondering if it might be possible to show the space is indeed symmetric by showing that the full curvature tensor is constant.

Comment: This is probably my ignorance of differential geometry, but what does it mean to ask that the full curvature tensor is constant, when it takes values in a nonconstant vector bundle (something like $T_M^{\otimes 4}$)?

Comment: By constant I meant that the derivative of the curvature with respect to the Levi-Civita connection vanishes. I know that's a necessary condition to being a symmetric space, but I'm not sure what else you need to add for it to be sufficient.

Comment: If the curvature is constant then the space is locally symmetric and so its universal cover is a (globally) symmetric space.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few comments:

1) I like the example of a cylinder, slightly more complicated than $S^n$.  This satisfies the constancy in the problem.  It is symmetric in having a transitive group of isometries, but the group of isometries is not doubly transitive.

2) We can solve the problem if for any points $p$ and $q$, we can exhibit an isometry $f$ taking $p$ to $q$.  And there is an obvious candidate for such an isometry:  Choose a geodesic $\gamma$ from $p$ to $q$.  Then parallel transport along $\gamma$ takes the tangent vectors at $p$ to tangent vectors at $q$, and takes small geodesics starting at $p$ to small geodesics starting at $q$.  This creates a map $f:B(p,r)\rightarrow B(q,r)$, where $r$ is the minimum of the radii of injectivity at $p$ and $q$.  We need to prove first that $f$ is an isometry on its domain, and then that $f$ can be extended to the whole space.

3) To prove that $f$ is an isometry, it suffices to show that the minimal ball $S$ containing $p_1$ and $p_2$ has the same volume as the minimal ball containing $f(p_1)$ and $f(p_2)$.  Then, by David Speyer's reformulation of the hypothesis, the two balls have the same radii, and the same diameters, and the same distance from $p_1$ to $p_2$ as from $f(p_1)$ to $f(p_2)$.  This may be useful because if $S$ has (e.g.) twice the volume of $f(S)$, then we can identify a decreasing sequence of balls $S_i$ where $S_i$ has twice the volume of $f(S_i)$, so we can identify a particular point where the isometry fails.

Comment: Could you explain how to construct that decreasing sequence? I feel like if we can the distance from $p_1$ to $p_2$ to be on an arbitrarily small scale, it's probably possible to finish the proof using local geometry, so this is a very good analysis.

Comment: Fill S with lots of disjoint small balls, so the volume of S is the sum of their volumes.  At least one of them, say S1, has at least twice the volume of f(S1).  Then fill S1...